# java.lang.Runnable vs System.Delegate

Tags: java, .net, jvm, clr

I've used both a fair bit but I don't know much about them under the hood.  How are they different and how are they the same?  To me they seem pretty similar and I would use them both in about the same way, although sadly java doesn't have lambda expressions and I don't see how to use Runnable in a type safe manner.

Specifically I'm talking about java.lang.Runnable in the Oracle JVM not in J# vs how the .Net runtime uses System.Delegate.

Comment: I believe Java 8 will have lambda expressions.

Comment: `java.lang.Runnable` is just an interface, it's a completely different thing from `System.Delegate`. Not sure why you're comparing one to the other.

Comment: System.Delegate doesn't seem much different so it's an abstract class and not an interface, but other than a little syntactic sugar it seems  to me to be nearly identical.  If you believe it's significantly different please elaborate how?  I'm genuinely curious because I use them both nearly identically in their respective languages. Aside from .Net events and lambdas.  I seem them as pretty much the same so I'm trying to figure out how they're different.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to Java, there is nothing special about Runnable, except inasmuch as thread support and the java.util.concurrent library are built to work with it.  It is just another interface.  If you don't like the fact that it has void return type, you can use Future< T >, or roll your own.  However you do it, the resulting code is going to be unsatisfactory, at least until Java 8 is mainstream.

Comment: I'm not complaining about the lack of lambdas or trying to say either Runnable or Delegate are better.  Since you said there is nothing special about Runnable does that mean you see something special about Delegate?